# Upload a file to php server with filename in the url

Tags: php, html, url, file-upload

I have a file named "test.txt" which I need to upload to a php server. The contents of the file changes but the file name does not. I want to automate it using curl (it is being upload from a unix box).

So the url would look like:  ***curl [http://myserver.com/upload.php?fname="test.txt"](http://myserver.com/upload.php?fname=%22test.txt%22)***

I am having a problem with the php code to accept the file name automatically. I am able to upload the file using the html input/submit, but that requires manual intervention.

Here is the code I have. I works properly for manual input. Can some please show me how to change the manual input to auto (from the url)?

I am fairly new to php so any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['fname'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['fname']['name'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['fname']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['fname']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['fname']['name'])));
      
      $extensions= array("txt");
      
       if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"download/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>
      
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="fname" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ADyson But that is not the question the OP ask, not the actual issue.

Comment: I'd say all you need to change is this `$file_name = $_FILES['fname']['name'];` to that `$file_name = $_GET['fname'];` , since you want to use the name specified as a GET parameter instead of the name specified in the file upload itself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, arkascha, however that did not work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Just submitting a file _name_ in the URL would not upload the file itself. If you want to upload a file automatically you need to write (or find online!) a script which actually sends the correct POST request in multipart format (to mimick what your browser does).

Comment: If you have a solution that's great, but please write it as an Answer below, for the benefit of everyone (including you, because then you can receive upvotes on it). Comments are not searchable. Take the [tour] if you need guidance on how stackoverflow is structured. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** The php file is fine as is. The solution lies in the correct curl script. In this case: ***curl -F "uploadedfile=@/path/to/my/file" mywebserver.com/uploads.php*** This will post the file name into the query without user intervention. Thank you to those who gave advice.